# ExpandableListView + BaseExpandableListAdapter: can add items but can't clear the list

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an `ExpandableListView` that uses a very primitive `BaseExpandableListAdapter` implementation. It takes an `ArrayList` and fetches the data from that list:

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    public ListAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<MyListItem> itemContainer) {
        m_inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        m_items = itemContainer;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return m_items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = m_inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_header, parent, false);
        }

        TextView label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemHeader);
        label.setText(String.valueOf(m_items.get(groupPosition).version) + " (" + m_items.get(groupPosition).date + ")");

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = m_inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_description);
        label.setText(m_items.get(groupPosition).description);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

    LayoutInflater m_inflater = null;
    ArrayList<MyListItem> m_items = null;
}
```

The activity holds the "original" `ArrayList<MyListItem>` and manipulates it. When an item is added, it does this:

```
 m_items.add(new ListItem(itemId, version, dateString, description));
 m_listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And that works. But clearing the list does not!

```
void clearList() {
    m_items.clear();
    m_listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I have, of course, checked that the code that clears the list is actually called. So what's the problem?

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: @AdrianOlar: as I said, there's no error. The list simply does not become empty after calling `m_items.clear()` + `m_listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: From where you're calling *m_items.clear();*? inside the adapter?

Comment: @Rami: from the activity which creates this container and passes a reference to it down to the adapter. I did check that `ListAdapter.m_items` has the size of 0 after I call `m_items.clear()` in the activity.

Comment: Could you please post the code that calls the clear() method?

Comment: @LiquidPenguin: I already have, it's the bottom-most piece of code in my question.

Comment: Location wise in you activity.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Try to add a clear method in your adapter and clear m_items inside it. Because i think you're clearing another reference of the ArrayList.

Comment: @LiquidPenguin: it's a separate method of the activity. Let's say it's called via a button click. I don't see how it can be important.

Comment: @Rami: I did that just now. No change. The view keeps getting more and more items because `clear` has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

In your method that does the clear data logic in your activity, Add this:

```
public void clearList()
    {
        m_items.clear();
        m_listAdapter=new ListAdapter(this,m_items);
        <your_expandableListView_name>.setAdapter(m_listAdapter)
    }
```

Comment: Why do I need to create a new adapter and pass it to the view again? I already have an adapter that is already assigned to the view! I'm aware the list can be cleared by calling `setAdapter(null)`, but it's silly, superfluous and non-optimal.

Comment: Yes it is non-optimal but it works. There could be several reasons why notifyDatasetChanged() wont work but this almost always works. Try to add this in your clearList() after `m_items.clear` : `m_items.addAll(new ArrayList<MyListItem>());` . The clearList() should now contain: `m_items.clear(); m_items.addAll(new ArrayList<MyListItem>());  m_listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`